# What sum operator does in this mysql view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code in mysql view:

```
    SELECT
        reports.date AS date,
        reports.book_title AS book_title,
        sum(
            (
                (
                    reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_list_price
                ) / conversion_rates.one_usd_value
            )
        ) AS revenue
  FROM
    (
        reports
        LEFT JOIN conversion_rates ON (
            (
                reports.currency = conversion_rates.currency
            )
        )
    )
  GROUP BY
        reports.date,
        reports.book_title
```

Can anyone tell what this code does?
I understand everything except  this block:

```
sum(
    (
        (
            reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_price
        ) / conversion_rates.one_usd_value
    )
) AS revenue
```

Comment: it sums up the value of the product of net_sold_count and avg_price divided by one_usd_value

Comment: It sums the result of expression per group (date & book_title)

Comment: 2 pairs out of the 3 pairs of parentheses are not needed.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about this? If you are literally just asking what the `sum` function in `mysql` does did you try googling `sum mysql`? and the rest is standard arithmetic.

Comment: You can make it easier to read by removing the backticks, they're unnecessary as the query expression isn't using any MySQL keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is unnecessarily verbose and can be simplified by removing redundant column aliases, backticks and parentheses:

```
SELECT
    reports.`date`
    reports.book_title
    SUM( reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_list_price / conversion_rates.one_usd_value ) AS revenue
FROM
    reports
    LEFT JOIN conversion_rates ON reports.currency = conversion_rates.currency
GROUP BY
    reports.`date`,
    reports.book_title
```

There, much more readable!

Anyway. The query, with the `SUM` part, with the `GROUP BY` means that:

1. For all rows in the `reports` table

   1.1. Get the `conversion_rate` value (`one_usd_value`)
2. Partition all of the rows into groups, such that each group has the same `date` and `book_title` values.
3. For each group:

   3.1. For each row in group:

   3.1.1. Multiply the row's `net_sold_count` with `avg_list_price`, which I assume is in a local currency, then divide by the `one_usd_value` value (obtained in step 1.1) to convert it to USD. Note that `a*b/c` is the same as `(a*b)/c` as multiplication is commutative, so the parenthesis are redundant.

   3.2 Sum-up each of the values computed in step 3.1.1

   3.3. Output one row for each group, containing the group's uniform `date`, `book_title` and `SUM` values.

You could also express it as a subquery, by performing the per-row `a*b/c` computation in a subquery before the `GROUP BY`/`SUM` is performed:

```
SELECT
    date,
    book_title,
    SUM( book_revenue ) AS revenue
FROM
(
    SELECT
        reports.`date`,
        reports.book_title,
        reports.net_sold_count,
        reports.avg_list_price,
        conversion_rates.one_usd_value,
        ( net_sold_count * avg_list_price / one_usd_value ) AS book_revenue
    FROM
        reports
        LEFT JOIN conversion_rates ON reports.currency = conversion_rates.currency
) AS [inner]
GROUP BY
    `date`,
    `book_title`
```